# On what scriptural/traditional bases do some churches allow gay marriage?

Tags: scriptures, same-sex-marriage

I have seen some pro-gay-marriage churches lately. The thing is, I don't understand on what scriptural or traditional (to include Old Catholics and Anglicans) do they take such a stance?

I'm not for or against it. I'm just asking how they do support their position.

Comment: Great question!  It's been asked before though, so it's been closed as a duplicate.  Hope you find the answers on the linked question helpful.